# define multiple variables on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I am struggling to define multiple variables:

```
var city_NAME = ("Birmingham" , "London"); 

//**various code i can't share**

if(thisLoc.getName() == City_NAME) {
```

The issue solely lies on the:

```
var city_NAME = ("Birmingham" , "London");
```

because it is only printing out the *second* city (London)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Apologies, i have 12 minutes to fix this issue. I am non javascript and have been let down by my contractor

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()`, and then either:

1. Make it an array

   ```
   var CITY_NAMES = ["Birmingham", "London"];
   ```

   or
2. Declare two variables

   ```
   var CITY_NAME1 = "Birmingham",
       CITY_NAME2 = "London";
   ```

I'd strongly recommend #1.

By including the `()`, you're grouping the items on the right-hand side into an expression with the comma operator. The comma operator is interesting: It evaluates its left-hand operand, then throws that result away, evaluates its right-hand operand, and takes that result.

Comment: Number one has worked. Excellent, thank you SO much.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of expression `("Birmingham" , "London")` will return `"London"`.

The expression evaluates before is being assigned to a variable. This is why the `city_NAME` variable equals `"London"`. You cannot pass multiple variables like that.

**Possible fix:**

You could, however, create an array of cities like this

```
var city_NAME = ["Brimingham", "London"];
```

and then check if your city exists in the array using [indexOf() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if(city_NAME.indexOf(thisLoc.getName()) !== -1) {
   //(...)
}
```